# iOS UIWebview, Disable double taps, allow sing tap WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, swift3, ios10

I am getting an issue with my implementation of ios app, i cant keep single taps on UIWebview enabled and disable double taps at same time. How can i disable double taps on a uiwebview while still allow single taps? i will not have access to the web pages JavaScript, and i want the single taps to be handled by the web page not on ios side. I have already tried other solutions,  i can detect double taps or disable all taps but  i have not been able to find a solution for both my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set numberOfTapsRequired to 1 for your UIWebview gesture recognizer.